# Replaceing Component in OpenMDAO Group

Tags: openmdao

In OpenMDAO 0.x there was a 'replace' method that let you swap components, not clear you can do that easily in 1.x.  I have Problem that my outer loop algorithm has to run multiple times, and in some cases want to swap the computationally expensive custom MDA component out for a MetaModel Component which has the same i/o.  Is there a quick and dirty way to do this at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I would just define a custom group class that takes an argument telling it which one to use. Rather than use a `replace` I suggest just re-instantiating the whole problem and calling setup again.

If, for some reason you don't want to call setup more than once (maybe its a big model and setup is slow), then I suggest you just create two problem instances. One will have the MMDA and the other will have the meta-model. In your outer loop you can just call whichever one is appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds confusing to combine MetaModel and MDA problems.  Having a MDA model suggests that the problem params and model are explicit, while the MetaModel suggests that the problem params and model are implicit which are two very different problems.  Running two different problems conditionally seems contrary to the MDAO paradigm of a single system of non-linear equations and could get very messy to implement, IMHO.

If the intent of the MetaModel is to refine the initializing guess for the MDA, then perhaps the Component Implicit State concept in v1.7 is the built-in method to employ in the MDA problem and abandon the MetaModel thus reducing the problem to one set of equations?  Beware that I have not tested the Component Implicit State method.

Otherwise, all OpenMDAO classes are just python classes and can have their solve_nonlinear methods modified to include conditional logic.  Perhaps your project could create a parent problem and a parent group which control conditionally the execution of the solver and the data flows as needed between the MetaModel and the custom MDA?

Your thoughts?

Comment: Its possible to replace an MDAO with a meta-model that fits the converged (feasible) solution space, so I don't see that as a fundamental problem. However, I agree that it would be possible to build a custom group/component that could swap out solve_nonlinear behavior conditionally. It might just be simpler to re-initialize the problem and call setup when this change is needed though.