# How to re-run problem with different model in for loop?

Tags: openmdao

I'm doing a design study that requires me to run many optimization problems on different models. My issue is that any optimization after the first fails. For example, I run study 1 first and the problem converges. Then I run studies 2, 3, 4, etc and the problems fail. However, if I start by running study 2 first, the problem converges. Then I can run studies 1, 3, 4, etc and the problems fail.
It seems someone has had a similar problem in the past and I've done as described in the previous post: [Replaceing Component in OpenMDAO Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746827/replaceing-component-in-openmdao-group).
Psuedo-code for my problem is provided below:

```
for i in range(N):
    p = om.Problem()
    add_subsystem(Model i)
    add driver and solvers
    add constraints
    add design variables
    add objective
    p.setup()
    set initial guesses
    run driver and save data
    p.cleanup()
    del p
```

As you can see, I cleanup, delete, and re-instantiate the problem at every iteration of the for loop. However, all optimizations after the first fail. Do you know why this process would fail? Is there anyway to correct it?

Also, to be clear, every model is uniquely structured with different variables, so I cannot simply change specific parameter values and just re-run the driver.

Comment: How is the process failing?  Is the optimizer running but failing to converge?  Does the failure occur before the optimizer runs?

Comment: The optimizer fails to converge (iteration limit reached). I can run each model individually by manually re-runnning the script and all models take about 5-10 iterations to converge. However, when running the models in the for loop, the first model takes 5-10 iterations to converge, but subsequent models reach the 200 iteration limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given much detail, but if your pseudocode is a good match to your model then the problem is not related to OpenMDAO itself. No state is shared between multiple problem instances. The behavior you are seeing is stateful though.

So something in one of your components or groups must be storing state somehow. Either writing something to a file that gets read by the next case, storing values in a global variable of some kind, or calling out to a compiled library that is stateful in some way.

Without more details on your model or an example case of some kind its hard to be more specific.

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. And yes, the psuedo-code matches the true code very well. To provide more details, I'm using the nonlinear Newton Solver and direct linear solver. I use the ScipyOptimizer driver with default options. I forgot to mention, my model has two subsystem models. The first is a custom explicit component that automatically generates a model from some .csv files. The second is a ExecComp() that sums the output of the explicit component.

Comment: Let me also provide more details about the custom model explicit component. Each model is stored a a directory (model1, model2, etc). In each directory there is a .csv file, a function that calculates the model outputs, and a function that calculates the model partials. In the `setup()` function, I call a custom function that imports the .csv (via pandas) and python functions and stores them in the model. The python functions are loaded by adding the folder to my path via the sys package `sys.path.insert(0,'model i')` and importing the module via importlib `fx=impL.import_module('X')`.

Comment: From the imported module, I load the function `CalcOut = getattr(fX, 'CalcOut')`. The remainder of the `setup()` function adds inputs and outputs based on the information in the .csv file. The model outputs are computed in the `compute()` function by calling my custom function (e.g. `CalcOut`). The model partials are computed in `compute_partials()` by calling my other custom function (e.g. `CalcPartial`).

Comment: I hope that is sufficient detail? Based on your response, my guess is that adding a directory to my path within the component may be an issue? Also, if it helps, I'm on OpenMDAO version 3.9.2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have resolved the issue. You were correct that one of the other packages was saving the state of the model without my knowing. The issue was the importlib package which was always importing functions from the same directory even after that directory was removed from my path. To fix the issue, the modules are imported via: `fX = importlib.import_module('model1.CalcOut')`. How would you like me to update this post?

Comment: You can just accept the answer. Your comments make it clear what the problem was and how you fixed it.